# ffmpeg "Option preset not found."

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv

I am trying to convert a .mpg to .flv with ffmpeg. On other servers I got it working but here with the ffmpeg clone (avconv) it just does not do it.

Originally I was working with libfaac and preset fastfirstpass but thats not available in this build so I switched to the experimental acc and preset libx264-fast_firstpass:

```
$ /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /data/upload/videos/original/150128_Test_731_9d5b83.mpg
  -strict experimental -acodec aac -ab 128k -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 -pass 1 
  -pre libx264-fast_firstpass -b 512k -s 360x204 
  -f flv /data/upload/videos/encoded/150129_Test_731_54f06a.flv

avconv version 9.16-6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Aug 10 2014 18:16:02 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
[mpeg @ 0xc87de0] max_analyze_duration reached
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, mpeg, from '/data/upload/videos/original/150128_Test_731_9d5b83.mpg':
  Duration: 00:01:00.12, start: 0.989978, bitrate: 4814 kb/s
    Stream #0.0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 720x406 [PAR 406:405 DAR 16:9], 104857 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0.1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 224 kb/s
[libx264 @ 0xc8b4c0] using SAR=136/135
[libx264 @ 0xc8b4c0] MB rate (26910000) > level limit (2073600)
[libx264 @ 0xc8b4c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0xc8b4c0] profile Main, level 5.2
[libx264 @ 0xc8b4c0] 264 - core 142 r2389 956c8d8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0 me=dia subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=30 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=512 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.25 aq=1:1.00
Option preset not found.
```

What does the error in the last line mean?

I already made sure the preset libx264-fast_firstpass.avpreset exists in /usr/share/avconv/ and if I change it to invalid ffmpeg complains with `Preset invalid specified for stream 0:0, but could not be opened.`, so the preset is correct.

Google does provide two results for this error. This [chatlog](https://mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel-irc/2014-April/002033.html) and it's [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/6zzDGEEt) about live streaming with the solution to add -f flv and some [russian page](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.ubuntu.ru%2Findex.php%3Ftopic%3D236047.0). Nothing helped.

Any advice?

Comment: A bit of advice. 1) Don't use avconv, use a real ffmpeg binary, this will clear out a lot of confusion when looking for examples. 2) you don't really need two-pass encoding unless you are targetting a specific output file size, which isn't the case here. 3) at least in ffmpeg, those preset files have been deprecated and removed a long time ago (2011 - see http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-cvslog/2011-April/036361.html). 4) be careful of examples in general, since they tend to be pretty outdated. The documentation at ffmpeg.org is usually the best up-to-date source of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look ìnto this preset file /usr/share/avconv/libx264-fast_firstpass and there I found this wrong "preset" option. I delete it and now it works.